# Execute custom script on save component config.xml

Tags: custom-component, custom-action, component-configuration

I am working on a custom component. The component has some component options, using the standard config.xml file and saving it to the extensions table.

But what if I need to execute a custom script when saving the component configs?
Depending on the settings of the component, I want to make some changes in the components db tables.

Is there a way provided by Joomla to add a script to the save event for component configs?

I'm still very new to Joomla component building. 
Any advice is most welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension plugin with `onExtensionAfterSave` event.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry

class PlgExtensionExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onExtensionAfterSave($context, $table, $isNew)
    {
        // Check that we're modifying the correct component.
        if ($context !== 'com_config.component' || $table->element !== 'com_content')
        {
            return;
        }

        // New component params.
        $params = new Registry($table->params);

        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

[Creating a Plugin for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)

Comment: Great, thanks, will try this.